# how to update plot and data table on multiple select of checkbox group input r shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

[on selection of multiple town](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwXB5.png)//server.r

## this code is working for a individual input but when i select multiple input it is not showing data as per input

```
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gridExtra)
library(DT)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(shinyWidgets)
dsn_driver = ""
dsn_database = ""            # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_hostname = "" # e.g.: "awh-yp-small03.services.dal.bluemix.net"
dsn_port = ""                # e.g. "50000"
dsn_protocol = ""            # i.e. "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = ""        # e.g. "dash104434"
dsn_pwd = ""
jcc = JDBC("", "");
jdbc_path = paste("jdbc:db2://",  dsn_hostname, ":", dsn_port, "/", dsn_database, sep="");
conn = dbConnect(jcc, jdbc_path, user=dsn_uid, password=dsn_pwd)
query ="select RETAIL_STR_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM as ST,RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.TOWN_NAME as TOWN_NAME,RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.AREA_NAME as AR,
ROUND(SUM(RETAIL_STR_SALES_MASTER.GRAND_TOTAL),2) as SALES_VALUE
from retail_str_sales_master, retail_store_area_wise
where retail_store_area_wise.store_id = retail_str_sales_master.store_id
GROUP  BY
RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM ,
retail_store_area_wise.area_name,
retail_store_area_wise.area_code,
retail_store_area_wise.town_name
ORDER BY RETAIL_STORE_AREA_WISE.STORE_NM,
retail_store_area_wise.area_name"
query1=dbGetQuery(conn,query)    

#Dropdown Function 



biz = data.frame(



Are=query1$AR,
TOWNNAME=query1$TOWN_N,
Storename=query1$ST,
Salevalue=query1$SALES_VALUE,
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


# connection with dash db
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(50000, session)
  output$Box1 = renderUI(selectInput("yr",label = "select a Area NAME",c(unique(isolate(biz$Are)),"pick one"),"pick one"))

  output$Box2 = renderUI(

    if (is.null(input$yr) || input$yr == "pick one"){return()
    }else checkboxGroupInput("sector", 
                      "Select a Town_Name", 
                      choices = c(unique(biz$TOWNNAME[which(biz$Are == input$yr)])),
                      "pick one")
  )  



  subdata1 = reactive(biz[which(biz$TOWNNAME== input$sector),])
```

not able to generate output on multiple select input it is working well on one select input but not in multiple select

```
output$text1 <- renderText({
        autoInvalidate()
        sprintf("Total value  of store per day", input$sector,"sales")
      })
  output$text2 <- renderText({
    autoInvalidate()
    sprintf("Total Number of bills per day", input$sector,"sales")

  })#not showing data as per the multiple checkbox group input working fine on single input select
  output$view = DT::renderDataTable({ 
    autoInvalidate()
    if(is.null(input$sector) ){return()
    } else if (input$sector == "pick one"){return()

    } else 
    {
      autoInvalidate()

      subdata1()[,c("TOWNNAME","Storename","Salevalue")]



    }
  },rownames = FALSE,class = 'cell-border stripe')



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({not ploting output as per the multiple checkbox input

    autoInvalidate()
    if (is.null(input$sector)){return()
    } else if(input$sector == "pick one") { return()
    } else p <- ggplot(data=subdata1() ,aes(x =Storename, y = Salevalue,group=Storename),environment=environment())+ geom_histogram(stat = "identity",aes(fill = type),fill = "blue")+ 

        geom_smooth() + ggtitle("ggplot")   

    print(p + theme(axis.text.x =
                      element_text(size  = 10,angle = 45,hjust = 1,vjust = 1)))    })
  })
```

//ui.r

```
library(RJDBC)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gridExtra)
library(DT)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)
```

dashboardPage(
     dashboardHeader(title = "STORE ANALYTICS"),
      dashboardSidebar(

```
    sidebarMenu(menuItem("Per Day Sales", tabName = "root", icon = icon("calendar"),uiOutput("Box1"),
      uiOutput("Box2")

    ))
  ),
  dashboardBody(

    fluidPage(

       displaying output of the ggplot
      fluidRow(



    box(
              width = 20, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
              title = textOutput("text1"),
              plotlyOutput(paste('plot'))),




           #data table output displaying here
            box(               
              width = 8, status = "info", solidHeader = TRUE,
              title = "STORE SALES PER MONTH ",
              dataTableOutput("view")

               )

          )

        )  

      )
    )
```

Comment: help me out with this code i am struggling with this

Comment: reproducibility is an issue with your code since it uses jdbc. Nevertheless, I'd first check with your nested ```ifelse```

Comment: i dont know any approach to resolve this issue

Comment: When you mean multiple selection is it box1 and box2?

Comment: I had attached a image above please have a look in image i had selected "colombo 11"and "colombo10" it is showing the random data after selecting the checkbox more than one

Comment: Couldn't see any image, Please check!

Comment: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwXB5.png" here is the link have a look

Comment: so your town name is a sub category of area name?

Comment: yes it is and after selecting two town name it is showing random data

Comment: hye any approach or any other way to solve this issues

Comment: First, Try printing the selection as text - we'll get to know if multiple selections are being treated as a vector!

Comment: No it is not treated as vector

Comment: That's the catch, you are using character to verify and it turns out to be a vector!

Comment: it is printing values like this [1] "colombo 10"   "colombo11" i think it is treating as a vector. but as a one vector

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, you need to filter it based on the vector not just a character.

Comment: i dont know any approach to do this

Comment: Ideally you should use dplyr filter for filter, that'd help you!

Comment: ok thanks for your help i will try to solve this issue by doing this

Comment: can you please let me know any approach

Comment: ```subdata1 = reactive(biz[which(biz$TOWNNAME== input$sector),])``` this is the place i think you have to change!

Comment: still not getting any approach to solve this

Comment: Any help still stuck on this